# Perl: Signal handler: Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference

Tags: perl, signals

I have the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use Fcntl ':flock';
use strict;
...
    my (@list, $fh);
    open $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $file or die "$file: $!";
    flock $fh, LOCK_EX;
    use sigtrap 'handler' => sub {flock($fh, LOCK_UN);}, 'normal-signals'; # line 72
```

It runs but gives an error when I press `^C`:

```
$ verify.pl
...
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at ./verify.pl line 72.
```

The docs says it's OK

```
$ perldoc sigtrap
...
        use sigtrap 'handler' => \&my_handler, 'normal-signals';
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest that `$fh` is the undefined symbol reference.  The `use` is run during the compilation phase (as if in a `BEGIN {...}` block), and, depending on where you think you're calling it, the `$fh` may never have been opened, or its scope may not be what you think.

Add some debugging to your handler to show, for example, the value of $fh and the `refaddr` of $fh.  Also add to your open/flock code the same.  I bet the refaddr isn't the same.

Since the sigtrap is registered globally, you may be best off with a global, e.g.:

```
my @handlers;
use sigtrap handler => sub { $_->() for grep defined, @handlers }, 'normal-signals';

{
  my ($fh, @list);
  open my $fh, ...
  flock $fh, LOCK_EX;
  my $handler = sub { flock $fh, LOCK_UN };

  @handlers = map { weaken $_ } grep defined, @handlers, $handler;
  # ... do stuff. When $handler goes out of scope, it'll go undef in @handlers
}
```